# Splitting xmlhttp.responseText row by row?

Tags: javascript

How can I split up xmlhttp.responseText I receive from a database select row by row?
My database layout contains 3 columns which I want to hand over to a function.

This is what the responsetext looks like:

```
75px, 218px, foo, 12px, 13px, bar, 27px, 37px, bla
```

The function should be called:

```
myfunction(75px, 218px, foo)
```

and so on.

Can anybody show me an example code?

Comment: Where is your problem at server level client level? What does the output look like?

Comment: Wouldn't returning a JSON encoded result me more feasible for this? It would help prevent issues with database fields containing row delimiters, etc.

Comment: There's absolutely no possible way anybody can answer the question if you don't show how your response text looks in the first place. (Why isn't that obvious?)

Comment: Ok, sorry.

This is what the responsetext looks like:

    75px, 218px, foo, 12px, 13px, bar, 27px, 37px, bla

The function should be called:
myfunction(75px, 218px, foo) and so on.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure you want to pass the `foo` object to the function? Or do you mean a string containing `"foo"`?

Comment: OK thanks @Bob - note that I edited the answer to call that little "trim" function to get rid of stray spaces that might be around the commas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "split" the text on the commas:

```
function handleResponse(rawResponse) {
  function trim(s) {
    return s.replace(/^\s*/, '').replace(/\s*$/, '');
  }

  var attrs = rawResponse.split(',');
  for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i += 3) {
    myFunction(trim(attrs[i]), trim(attrs[i + 1]), trim(attrs[i + 2]));
  }
}
```

*edit* to actually call the "trim" function I took the trouble to include :-)

Comment: Isn't it neater to extend the `String` object with `String.prototype.trim`? ;)

Comment: @Marcel well sure but I feel that it's a little dangerous to put stuff like that in Stackoverflow answers - you never know who'll find this question and just cut-paste the whole thing, and doing something like that could break unexpectedly